# How can I play multiplayer Among Us over LAN?

Tags: among-us

I want to do LAN play with my family.

How many people need to own the game to be able to play?
Do Android users not need to pay?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to ask, but you need a certain max for the LAN multiplayer games. As for the Android users question, no, the game is free on Google Play.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe Does each PC user have to buy the game?

Comment: @MarkGiraffe What do you mean by "You need a certain max for the LAN multiplayer games."

Comment: Then please edit out the "How many people need to own the game?" part. It looks like some opinion-based question and what you should've asked is if you need to buy it.

Comment: The max? Depending on the number of family members, you need a certain max for the amount of players you want to join in your game. However, if you have a big family and you want some (if not all) of them to play with you, you'll have bad luck considering the max amount for the max player count is 10, in any amount of imposters from the max of 3.

Comment: Playing with say 4 is okay though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120110/discussion-between-mark-giraffe-and-mckay).

Answer (score 2):

Everyone needs to own the game to play together. On Android and iOS, the game is free, however, it costs $5 on PC and Switch (and Switch Lite).

The max amount of players are 10 per game and can have a max of 3 imposters. Just something to keep in mind!

Comment: If you really don't want to pay the $5 on windows you can get bluestacks and get it for free on the google play

Comment: @Penguin Thanks!  I didn't think about that (Don't really deal with Android or play Among Us that much)

Comment: Yes, although I would advise you just get the $5 one unless you really can't, because you'd have to get another program for key bindings (otherwise you'll have to use only your mouse), run it under an emulator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed play this game with your family!
Everyone needs their own copy of the game on their own separate device.
The options are:

A five-dollar purchase for PC.

A free app for IOS

A free app for Android

A five-dollar purchase for Nintendo Switch

A five-dollar purchase for Switch Lite

All these versions of the game are cross-platform, and you can make a lobby, and share the code with the rest of your family.
All this is done over LAN.

Have Fun!

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the other answer.